# Convert jQuery Animation to React Hook

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an animation where the letters of two words appear one by one, similar to a slide-in effect. I have the code made with `jQuery`, but I need to implement it in my `React` app (built with hooks). The code that I have takes the text, splits it creating individual letters, and adds spans between those letters. This is the following code that I need to convert to `React`:

```js
const logoText = document.querySelector('.logo');
const stringText = logoText.textContent;
const splitText = stringText.split("");

for (let i=0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
     text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText + "</span>" 
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 50)
```

I was wondering if you guys could help me figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the text and create a timeout function for every letter with a different time of execution, that way will be visible the slide effect you are expecting:

#### Custom hook

```
const useSlideInText = text => {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Array.from(text).forEach((char, index) => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(
        () =>
          setSlide(prev => (
            <>
              {prev}
              <span>{char}</span>
            </>
          )),
        index * 100
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return slide;
};
```

#### Usage

```
 function App() {
    const slide = useSlideInText("hello");
    return (
      <div>
        {slide}
      </div>
    );
 }
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q9yzmr)

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much! and thank you for adding the working example, it made it much clearer. Sorry if I am over asking, but if you have another minute, I was wondering if you know how to make the text appear smoothly (ease transition, from 0 to 1 opacity), like it's drawn, instead of typed?

Comment: Your welcome, it feels good to help others. Do you need something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q9yzmr?file=src%2FApp.js, if you need to add some animation in that case you need to apply some changes to ensure that the animation does not repeat every time a letter is added. Also you can convert the hook into a functional component and pass the text as children

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. And you are right! the animation does repeat over... I am guessing there has to be something that modifies the state once all the characters have been printed out

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the React components that you want to run this hook in possess the text you want to split. I am also assuming that on the interval, you want to reveal more of the text. In that case my example solution would look like this:

Hook

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const useSlideInText = (text) => {
    const [revealed, setRevealed] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (revealed < text.length) {
            setTimeout(() => setRevealed(revealed + 1), 50);
        }
    });
    
    return text.split('').slice(0, revealed).map((char) => (<span>{char}</span>));
}
```

Example usage

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const displayText = useSlideInText(props.text);

    return <div>{displayText}</div>;
};
```

Comment: 2 things that are immediately concerning:

1: you define a useState/useEffect outside of your component, I'm not sure how well that works 2: the useEffect has no variables after you defined the function, so it will only run once. You will want to add [revealed] as the second argument to useEffect

Comment: 1. They are being called inside a hook, so the rules of hooks are still preserved (as long as this new custom hook is called correctly). This is how practically all non-react core hooks are formed.

Comment: 2. If you do not provide a second argument to useEffect, it will run after every render. Which will be useful in this case as the value of text may change. Of course you could restrict it to just when revealed, and/or text is changed as you said. To get a useEffect to run only once, you need to add an empty array as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

going off of the other answer:

```
const generateDisplayTest = (text, numChars) => text.split('').slice(0, numChars).map((char) => (<span>{char}</span>));

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [revealed, setRevealed] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (revealed < props.text.length) {
            setTimeout(() => setRevealed(revealed + 1), 50);
        }
    }, [revealed]);
    const displayText = generateDisplayTest(props.text, revealed);

    return <div>{displayText}</div>;
};
```

including `[revealed]` in the useEffect means that useEffect will run every time that `revealed` changes. Also I always feel that useState/useEffect should live on the component, it has been that way in the place I worked but I'm not sure if that is industry standard.